# Should I ask about free software repos here

Tags: discussion

I would be **very** interested to ask for a list of repos of free open code, applicable to **8-bit avr-s** and having relation to robotics - object avoidance, process controllers, battery management. This would be of huge help for me, preventing me from wasting weeks and months to invent the wheel.

I see two problems with this. First, the question is broad. Second, this is a list question.

How, if possible, can I shape my question in a form, that is appropriate for Robotics.SE?

Comment: It would be nice by the down voter to leave a comment about their reasoning. I think it's a very well put question that is explicitly aware that SE discourages broad and list questions and wonders how the question can be asked in a way that is suitable to the site

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not really possible. This used to be allowed (sort of) via "community wiki" questions, but [no longer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Broad/list questions are both actively discouraged here, this keeps the site material useful and relevant, without spiralling into forum-like anarchy.

Only place to ask would be on [Robotics chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221/robotics), but the room is currently deserted :\

What you *can* do is filter the libraries down to a few desirable ones, and ask specific questions about them--how to do various tasks with them. You may also ask comparison quesions, but tread carefully-- many of these can be Not Constructive. Make the aspect you are comparing (tht task you want to do/etc) clear, and it ought to be fine. For more info, see [Gorilla vs Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: The OP is aware that it's a list question and is asking if there's a wayto phrase this question in a non-list way. If you think that's impossible, I'd suggest adding that to your answer. At the moment, it slightly misses the point of the question

Comment: Well, I could ask a series of similar questions, less broad. Then every one of them would have a specific answer (a specific lib). IMO this would be *less* useful, than a community wiki post, collecting the not-so-abundant info in one article.

Comment: @Thomas, done, thanks :). I sorta misinterpreted the q...

Answer (score 1):

Questions about specific libraries for specific purposes are certainly on topic, e.g. is library X a good fit for task Y?

As the site evolves, more of these questions will pop up and they'll be tagged with the name of the library in question.

The tag wiki itself can then be a great resource for collecting links to tutorials, etc. A case in point would be the tag wiki for the C++ tag on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score -1):

Mark the community wiki checkbox when asking the question and immediately answer with what you have found so far. Make sure to organize you and others' answers so that the total end result is an equivalent of a high quality Wikipedia article.

Comment: As @Manishearth pointed out, community wiki is now actively discouraged